# Inconsistency between search jobs and search companies when selecting filters

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

If I'm on the **search jobs** tab and I hover over location and check off the checkboxes Allows Remote, Offers Relocation, and Offers Visa Sponsorship and **Search** I get something that looks like this:

[image]

If I do the same exact thing except on the **search companies** tab we get a different output:

[image]

The second one appears to be more wordy and loses its formatting / has a different style associated with it.  Obviously 2 different people were working on this.  Can we change this to follow the same text and formatting for consistency?

Comment: @TinyGiant Actually first one does include all 3, notice the part that says 13 _remote_  jobs.

Comment: Yeah, that copy is a bit unnatural. We'll get that fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the report. We now use the more natural syntax:

> 72 company pages which allow remote and offer relocation and visa sponsorship.